# TextFormField is losing focus after rebuilding inside BlocSelector in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I'm making a dynamic input form using `flutter_bloc` to manage form states.
I can add and remove the `TextFormField`.
The problem is inputs keep losing focus immediately after typing a word.
I understand that `BlocSelector` rebuilds its content when selected state is changed but I do not know how to persist the key for each input since my `TextFormField`s are dynamic

**My code**

```
class AddQuestionScreenBody extends StatelessWidget {
  AddQuestionScreenBody({super.key});
  final GlobalKey _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0, left: 15.0),
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            BlocSelector<AddQuestionBloc, AddQuestionState, List<String>>(
              selector: (state) => state.answerList,
              builder: (context, answerList) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    for (int i = 0; i < answerList.length; i++)
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          key: UniqueKey(),
                          initialValue: answerList[i],
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                              return "Answer is required";
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            context.read<AddQuestionBloc>().add(
                                  OnChangeAnswerElement(
                                    index: i,
                                    value: value,
                                  ),
                                );
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            label: Text('Answer ${i + 1}'),
                            suffixIconColor: Colors.redAccent,
                            suffixIcon: IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                context.read<AddQuestionBloc>().add(
                                    OnRemoveAnswerElement(
                                        i));
                              },
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.remove),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        context.read<AddQuestionBloc>().add(
                              OnAddAnswerElement(),
                            );
                      },
                      child: const Icon(Icons.add),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You need TextEditingController(s) for your fields, held in State.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Could you please make some edits in my code?

Comment: You should be googling for "flutter texteditingcontroller" for examples of proper use.

Comment: I do know the usage of TextEditingController but I do not know how it helps me in this case to persist the focus in the TextFormField. That's why I'm confusing with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide AddQuestionBloc to see do you rebuild screen on every change by doing:

```
context.read<AddQuestionBloc>().add(
                                  OnChangeAnswerElement(
                                    index: i,
                                    value: value,
                                  ),
                                );
```

And as you have TextFormField, may be you should rebuild hole screen on form submission only with onFieldSubmitted callback?

Also, try to set FocusNode() for each TextFormField.

So you need different keys, focus nodes and may be controllers for each TextFormField. It depends on your requirements.

Comment: Yes, I also thought about FocusNodes or TextEditingControllers but persist these things in Bloc is not recommended. So I comeback to the keys.

Comment: of course it should be done not in bloc

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause, BlocSelector rebuilds widget tree so the TextFormField will lose its key since I'm using `Unikey()` as the key. 
The solution is to create my own key for each TextFormField so I can persist the key regardless of Widget tree getting rebuilt.

```
class AddQuestionScreenBody extends StatelessWidget {
  AddQuestionScreenBody({super.key});
  final GlobalKey _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0, left: 15.0),
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            BlocSelector<AddQuestionBloc, AddQuestionState, List<String>>(
              selector: (state) => state.answerList,
              builder: (context, answerList) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    for (int i = 0; i < answerList.length; i++)
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          key: answerList[i].id, // CHANGE HERE
                          initialValue: answerList[i],
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                              return "Answer is required";
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            context.read<AddQuestionBloc>().add(
                                  OnChangeAnswerElement(
                                    index: i,
                                    value: value,
                                  ),
                                );
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            label: Text('Answer ${i + 1}'),
                            suffixIconColor: Colors.redAccent,
                            suffixIcon: IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                context.read<AddQuestionBloc>().add(
                                    OnRemoveAnswerElement(
                                        i));
                              },
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.remove),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        context.read<AddQuestionBloc>().add(
                              OnAddAnswerElement(),
                            );
                      },
                      child: const Icon(Icons.add),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```